# Replace capitalized letters in matching lines

Tags: replace, multiple-lines

I have multiple lines with the key "booktitle":

```
  booktitle={Advances in Cryptology - CRYPTO' 89 Proceedings},
  volume={435},
  series={Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
```

I would like to replace the uppercase letters of each value with {LETTER}, i.e.

```
  booktitle={{A}dvances in {C}ryptology - {CRYPTO}' 89 {P}roceedings},
  volume={435},
  series={Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 5):

To obtain this result you could use [`:substitute`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute), for example with the cursor on the first line:

```
:s/\u\+/{\0}/g
```

- `\u\+` one or more uppercase character: equivalent to `[A-Z]\+`, see[`:h \u`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cu)
- `\0` whole matched pattern, see [`:h sub-replace-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)
- `g` is a flag needed to replace all occurrences in the line unless `gdefault` is on

To affect more than one line, you can specify a [range](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges), e.g. `:%s` for the entire file.

In order to execute this substitution multiple times but only on lines starting with a defined pattern (`/^  booktitle=/` in this case), [`:global`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) is probably what you want:

```
:g/^  booktitle=/s/\u\+/{\0}/g
```

Comment: I just have a try, It works well, Thanks for your answer.